# Algorithm to extract Noun and Adjective from a free flowing String in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, nlp

I am working on a project in which i am stuck on a part where i have to find all the nouns and adjective from a free flowing text. I searched and found few algorithm but faced a lot of difficulty in implementation. So i need an API or efficient algorithm to do so..

Comment: This was the exact problem, Suppose there is a text "Tajmahal Is in Agra". so the solution text must contain all noun and adjectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an algorithm for so called *part of speech* (POS) *tagging*. Normally, these algorithms are statistical, and you cannot expect perfect performance. Others try to parse a sentence according to language grammar, but in real life not all sentences are grammatical. Also, there is a big problem of novel (i. e. not known to the program) words. For example, you would perfectly understand parts of speech in a contrived sentence "the moobza klucked a blone", but not every algorithm would.

On the practical side, look at Stanford NLP software, which also has [a .NET interface](http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/). It has a pretty mature and good performing POS tagger.